# Laravel password tag with Input Old

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

Here is my Tag for change the password.

```
{{ Form::text('OldPassword', Input::old('OldPassword'),  array('placeholder'=>'Old Password')) }}
```

It works good when i give `Form::text` but when i give as `Form::password`
It works at first time, Once the form is submitted while trying to `Input::old('OldPassword')`

I am getting

```
Illegal string offset 'name'
```

What is the mistake i am doing and how can i fix this ??

Answer (score 2):

`Form::password()` accepts 2 arguments :

```
Form::password($name, $options)
```

It's not necessary to initiate password input value because it's simply password ! So laravel does not consider it.

But it's achievable using `Form::input()`

```
Form::input('password', 'nameOfInput', 'someValue')

// In your case :
Form::input('password', 'OldPassword', Input::old('OldPassword'))
```